# Unable to print the content of array of objects in Grails

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy, gsp

**DOMAIN CLASS**

```
package marchmock2

class Pgtyp {
   Date date_hour
   String mv
   String pagetype
   Integer visits
   Integer visits_ly
   Integer visits_lw
   String time_period
   String platform
   String device
   String browser

   static mapping = {
      table "pgtyp"
      version false 
      date_hour column: "date_hour"
      mv column: "mv"
      pagetype column: "pagetype"
      visits column: "visits"
      visits_ly column:"visits_ly"
      visits_lw column:"visits_lw"
      time_period column:"time_period"
      platform column:"platform"
      device column:"device"
      browser column:"browser"
   }

   static constraints = {}
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
package marchmock2
import grails.converters.*
import groovy.sql.Sql   

class PgtypController {

   def ajaxGetMv = {
      def pgtyp = Pgtyp.executeQuery("select p.visits from Pgtyp p where p.mv = ?",["params.id"])            
      render pgtyp as JSON
   }

   def index() { 
   }
}
```

**GSP**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <g:javascript src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"/>
      <g:javascript src="prototype.js"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form>
         <g:select from="['AFFILIATES', 'SEO', 'SEM','DISPLAYADS']" name="mv"
            onchange="${remoteFunction(
            controller:'Pgtyp', 
            action:'ajaxGetMv', 
            params:'\'id=\' + escape(this.value)',
            onSuccess: 'printpgtyp(data)')}">
         </g:select>
      </form>
      <script>
         function printpgtyp(data) {
            console.log(data)
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am expecting an array of objects to be printed to the console. However, I am getting the following output in my console:

```
[
  each: function,
  eachSlice: function,
  all: function,
  any: function,
  collect: function …
]
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I am printing it or is it because the value from my GSP is not getting posted to the controller, somehow?

Comment: `["params.id"]` should be `[params.id]`

Comment: Is there some way I can send the result to GSP in the following format visits:123 visits:23 visits:12

Comment: Your code is file except the change I have mentioned above. It sends the data in the format [123, 23, 12,...]. Just traverse this.

Comment: What do you get if you open in the browser the `http://[[your_url]]/pgtyp/ajaxGetMv` url?

Comment: Also you may add logging right into the method if you want to know what method is get in the params. `def ajaxGetMv = { log.debug "params: $params"`

Comment: @user1690588 What should be done if I want to add multiple selects in one GSP and pass them all to the cotroller when either of the drop-down changes

Comment: For that one of the solution is: add a class to all the selects eg. `mySelects` and then change your remoteFunction `params:'\'id=\' + $(".mySelects").val()',` will sends all the values of the select to the controller.

Comment: can you post any link which I can refer to understand how does class work?Please

Comment: Please check the update in the question posted <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605495/multiple-gselect-in-one-gsp-and-multiple-params-in-hql-inside-controller>